# Node.js Socket.io Error when trying to connect client to server

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to create a Web chat and to do this 1st we need to set up a client to server connection via Node and Socket.io - and it is not working.

The server code is here:
https://collectiveboost.com/cb_node/chat_app/server.js

And it runs fine when started via: node server.js
printing results to putty command line of: “Socket io Server Chat Started...”

But on client side the socket.io connection is not happening :(
And we have tried it both ways, that is via global socket.io as you can see here:
https://collectiveboost.com/cb_node/chat_app/index.htm

this results in Error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught Reference Error: io is not defined at (index):14

And via local version of the client-side JS file which can be reached via: node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js
as stated on:
https://socket.io/get-started/chat

which you can see here:
https://collectiveboost.com/cb_node/chat_app/index_2.htm

this results in Error:
polling-xhr.js:157 GET https://collectiveboost.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nt9UN_R 404 (Not Found)

So what are we doing wrong?
How can we connect the client side Web page socket.io to server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

---

please try this code and its very usefull to you.
Its a basic simple chat system.

**Server Code**

```
var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index6.html');
    });
    var username = '';
    var rooms;
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log("User connected");
        socket.on('join', function(name) {
            username = name;
            //console.log(username)
            io.emit('chat-msg', `${username.toUpperCase()} Welcome`);
        })
        socket.join(rooms)
        socket.on('chat msg', function(msg) {
            //console.log(msg);
            io.sockets.in(rooms).emit('chat msg', msg)
                //console.log(array)
        })
    
        socket.on('disconnect', function(name) {
            console.log("disconnet")
            io.emit('chat-msg', `${username.toUpperCase()} disconnected`)
        })
    
    });
    
    http.listen(5600, function() {
        console.log('listening on localhost:5600');
    });
```

**Client Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div class="box">
        <ul id="messages">

        </ul>
        <ul id="messages1">
        </ul>

        <form action="">
            <input id="inp" placeholder="Enter your message..." autocomplete="off" required /><button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var name = prompt("enter name")
            var socket = io();
            socket.emit('join', name);


            $('form').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                socket.emit("chat msg", (name + " : " + $("#inp").val()));
                //$('#messages').append($('<li id="list">').text('You: ' +$('#inp').val()));
                $('#inp').val('');
            });

            socket.on('chat-msg', function(msg) {
                $('#messages').append($('<li id="list"><br>').text(msg));

            })
            socket.on('chat msg', function(msg) {
                $('#messages1').append($('<li id="list1"><br>').text(msg));

            })
            socket.on('left', function(data) {
                document.write(data.description)
            })
        </script>
    </div>
    <style>
        .box {
            border: 1px solid red;
            height: auto;
            width: 500px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 300px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 30px;
        }
        
        #inp {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            right: 200px;
            outline: none;
            border: soild blue;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 50px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        #list {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #6195e8;
            color: #fffafa;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        
        #list1 {
            text-align: right;
            background-color: #6bdde3;
            color: #ed001c;
        }
        
        button {
            color: White;
            background-color: green;
            width: 80px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 150px;
            bottom: 10px;
        }
        
        #messages li {
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
    </style>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I do have the code for the Chat. My question/problem is that the Socket.io code on client side is not establishing connection with the node based server part of the chat. That is this code is not resulting in browser to server connection:    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>  resulting in the Error that I have posted in the question.    That is all I need answer with. Thanks again all.

Comment: Try  this   <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-1fOn6VtTq3PWwfsOrk45LnYcGosJwzMHv+Xh/Jx5303FVOXzEnw0EpLv30mtjmlj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>